# How to say "I was/am annoyed with myself"?

Tags: words, usage

So I did something stupid today and I wanted to tell someone about it and say that "I was annoyed with myself for doing X".

My best guess is something like

> Xして、自分にイライラしちゃったの。

and

> 昨日Xして、自分にイライラしてるの。

But are these really a valid sentences? And if they are, do they mean what I want to say or do they mean something else?

> Please could someone explain to me how to say "I was/am angry at myself
>   that I did X yesterday"?

Comment: Could you describe the speaker (and the listener) a little bit?  Age, gender and such?  Plus, what kind of speech are you looking for?  Formal, informal, colloquial, slangy, etc.?

Comment: I hope you are a ♀ to speak like this.

Comment: I think 自分に腹が立った（[179,000 results](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E6%98%A8%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AF*%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AB%E8%85%B9%E3%81%8C%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&hl=ja#q=%22%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AB%E8%85%B9%E3%81%8C%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%22&newwindow=1&hl=ja&start=519&filter=0)） is more natural/common than 我ながら腹が立った...

Comment: (cont.) （[24 results](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E6%98%A8%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AF*%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AB%E8%85%B9%E3%81%8C%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&hl=ja#q=%22%E6%88%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8C%E3%82%89%E8%85%B9%E3%81%8C%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%22&newwindow=1&hl=ja&start=20&filter=0)）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say 昨日{きのう}Xをしてしまったので、我{われ}ながら腹{はら}が立{た}った/立{た}つ for "I was/am angry at myself that I did X yesterday."

BTW, I think Xして、自分にイライラしちゃったの is a neat translation for "I was annoyed with myself for doing X."

Comment: Thank you, your answer is helpful to me. Is 腹が立つ and イライラする more or less the same thing? Or does one mean "annoyed" and one "angry"? And thank you for introducing new vocabulary to me like 我ながら.

Comment: @user213845: You are welcome. 腹が立つ stands for "to be/ get angry" while "イライラする" stands for "to be/get frustrated, irritated, annoyed." They are similar, but my impression is 腹が立つ is stronger than イライラする. For the record you can use 激怒する to mean "to be outraged",

Answer (score 2):

In a more broken style (a little bit vulgar), you can also say:

- 自分にイラついた
- 自分にムカついた

Comment: if you can use those 2, cant you just do 自分に怒った

Comment: I think it's also fine.